# Customize T4 Scaffolding With PowerShell

Tags: powershell, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I want to create a **Custom Scaffolder** that uses arbitrary **PowerShell** logic. It can render **T4 templates** (multiple ones if I want), with the result being output:

- As a new file in your project
- as a new code block inserted into an existing class
- my PowerShell logic can use **Visual Studio**’s “code model” API to manipulate files and code elements in other arbitrary ways.

How to Customize T4 Scaffolding With PowerShell?

Comment: Scaffolding is a kind of template/wizard technique that provides some basic functionality for MVC apps. See [Example](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/:

> In Package Manager Console of Visual Studio execute the following
>   command :
>
> ```
> Scaffold CustomScaffolder ClassName
> ```
>
> This adds a CodeTemplates folder to your project, containing files for
>   the new scaffolder.
>
> As you can see, we’ve got two files:
>
> - **A PowerShell script (.ps1)**, where we can put arbitrary logic to decide what templates get rendered and where the output goes. By
>     default, it renders a T4 template and uses the output to create a new
>     file called ExampleOutput in the root of your project.
> - **A T4 template (.t4)**, i.e., the thing that the default .ps1 file renders. By default this generates a simple C#/VB class (depending on
>     your project type). If you want to see this working, you can run the
>     custom scaffolder right away:
>
>   `Scaffold ClassName`
>
> This will generate a new class file, ExampleOutput.cs, in the root
>   folder of your project. That’s really just to show you how it works.
>   We don’t really want that, so don’t run the new scaffolder yet, or if
>   you already have done, delete ExampleOutput.cs